# Power Spectral Density vs Frequency Domain separation

Tags: frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density

I am just starting to learn about Power Spectral Density (PSD). What I'm reading is that it is possible to separate PSD masks if they are isolated, even if the frequencies do overlap. My understanding is that this is how telephone lines for example can carry both telephone and adsl signals simultaneously.

Now, I also came across a claim that frequency isolation is a "sufficient but not necessary condition" for signals to be separatable. Does this mean that if the frequencies are isolated, then the PSD signals do *not* need to be isolated? In other words, isolation of one or the other is sufficient?

Please excuse any wrong terminology, and I welcome corrections. I'm quite new is this field, so appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "isolation"?  Common ways of separating signals are in time (TDMA), frequency (FDMA) and code space (CDMA). So even if signals occupy the same spectral frequencies, they can still be separated with use of orthogonal codes, or transmitting in different time slots, or both.

Comment: By isolation, I mean that they don't overlap. So I think what you're saying is that the frequencies can overlap and you can still separate them. I think I intuitively get that. The PSDs cannot overlap in the same way as the frequencies can, right? Is this always the case? Does it change if the frequencies are disjoint (do not overlap). (again, I'm stoll trying to grok the terminology so sorry if I get it wrong)

Comment: PSD is an average measurement so yes the PSD’s can overlap.